# Handling Click Event for menu Used for Floating Action Button Options

Tags: android

I used a library recently that Provides a Floating Action Button and changing to a Something like Navigation bar by clicking on it.
but i cant set click Event for my navigation bar Items.
after Pressing on items i don't see any reaction!
Anyone can help me?

```
     fabOptions = (FabOptions) findViewById(R.id.fabcontainer);
    fabOptions.setButtonsMenu(R.menu.menu1);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.back:
            newBack();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void newBack() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: you should edit your code snipet here, it is a bit messy

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have to use break whenever you use switch statement otherwise the program will go to default status. so use break; the code below.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getId(); // Retrieve the id of the selected menu item

    switch(id) {
        case R.id.back: 
            newBack();
            return true;
            break;
        case ...
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```